# Overloading operator >>

Tags: c++

I have a template and I can't overload operator >> from cout.

```
template <class C> class Fract {
/*some fields*/
friend std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& out, Fract f);
};
```

When  I write it, gcc (CodeBlocks) write me, that this function isn't template (non-template), but how I know, template scope is spread from { to }. How is it?
I try other code:

```
template <class C> class Fract {
/*some fields*/
std::ostream& std::operator<<(Fract f);
};
```

And it isn't work. I think I must use something like that:

```
std::ostream<C>& std::operator<<(Fract f);
```

But I can't write it right. Can you help me?

UPD: Thank you, in real programm this mistakes aren't present!

Comment: `std::operator>>` is used for input. I strongly advise against using it for output.

Comment: You are also missing a ; after the last brace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define it like following outside of class `Fract`

```
template <class C>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Fract<C>& f)
{
    // ....
    return out ;
}
```

<sup>***SEE [HERE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85b02c39da1afa90)***</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working! Is it normal, if gcc write me "Warning: friend declaration (my function) declares a non-template function" ???